# jquery unexpected call to method or property access ie error

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

Friends need help to resolve this issue.

```
(function($){

   $('*').each(function(){

if ($(this).children().length == 0) { 



          $(this).html($(this).html().replace(avidno,'<span id=avidlocal>AvidTrak Tracking Number</span>')); 

     } 



   });



})(jQuery)
```

Comment: And at which line is the issue?

Comment: $(this).html($(this).html().replace(avidno,'<span id=avidlocal>AvidTrak Tracking Number</span>'));

Comment: Here is the working page but in ie through error:
http://jsfiddle.net/webdesignerart/zGgC7/

Comment: You cannot just copy and past your HTML into jsFiddle. You are loading jQuery from `localhost` which is not accessible outside your computer. Maybe this is correct: http://jsfiddle.net/zGgC7/1/

Comment: Yes Agree but no luck in IE:
http://jsfiddle.net/webdesignerart/zGgC7/2/
Unexpected call to method or property access error in IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the following line is what's giving you the error:

```
$(this).html($(this).html().replace(avidno,'<span id=avidlocal>AvidTrak Tracking Number</span>'));
```

you should break it up so that only one method is being called per line. This will allow you to further isolate the error. For example:

```
var obj = $(this);    
var currentHTML = obj.html();
var newHTML = currentHTML.replace(avidno,'<span id=avidlocal>AvidTrak Tracking Number</span>');
```

If the `var currentHTML` line is the issue, then $(this) is probably undefined for some reason. Or perhaps you need quotes around the id name "avidlocal". Hard to say, since this is an IE bug after all, and I don't see anything specific that I know doesn't work in IE.

As a final note, I would strongly advise your friend to find a better way to achieve what he's aiming. $('*').each will loop through every single element on the page. Does your friend really not have any way of producing HTML that allows the "avidno" text to be more easily replaced, i.e. more easily accessed via jQuery (through a class/id) than by looping through everything and checking if they have children nodes?

Comment: WAOn thankx its remove the error but replcement not work, is i have to do this now: $("body").html(newHTML);

Comment: i Changed the
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(avidno,'<span id=avidtoll>AvidTrak Tracking Number</span>'));
to
var newAvidno = $('body').html().replace(avidno,'<span id=avidtoll>AvidTrak Tracking Number</span>');
            document.body.innerHTML = newAvidno;
and its works nice.